# NodeJs SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to implement promises in sequences with async and export this function. However I am getting syntax error

```
exports.editImage = function(sourceBucket, sourceKey, options) {
    const imagePath = await downloadImage({
      Bucket: sourceBucket,
      Key: sourceKey,
    });
    const info = await imageInfo(imagePath);
    const imageBuffer = await resizeImage(imagePath, info, options);
    const result = await uploadImage(imageBuffer, info, options);
    return result;
};
```

Error

> 'const imagePath = await downloadImage({',
>   '^^^^^^^^^^^^^',
>   '',
>
> 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier',`

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` can only be used in an `async` function.

Set your function as async:

```
exports.editImage = async function(sourceBucket, sourceKey, options) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget async:

```
exports.editImage = async function(sourceBucket, sourceKey, options) {
```